# CSS media query to detect width double the height?

Tags: css, media-queries

Hi I have a full screen web app (site) and some people have really wide screens, or regular screens with a bunch of toolbars in their browser that makes the width of the viewable area over double the height, and I want to load different images for that case.

Is there a way to do something like
min-device-aspect-ratio: 2
or
width >= height * 2
?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the `min-aspect-ratio` and `max-aspect-ratio` CSS media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

You can then use CSS to specify a different image (as a background image) based on the aspect ratio.

```css
/* regular, default image */
#myImage {background-image: url(...)}

/* image to use when screen width is more than double the height */
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
    #myImage {background-image: url(...)}
}
```